# Are c++/cx private destructors thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, uwp, c++-cx

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/ref-classes-and-structs-c-cx), c++/cx *private* destructors are “only invoked when the reference count reaches zero.”

Thus, would it be safe to say that no other threads can be manipulating an object when its private destructor is invoked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell, yes.

It's possible someone else could still have references to the class if they did things like cast it to a raw pointer without wrapping it in a `ComPtr` etc. but that's just buggy code that's going to crash sooner or later anyway.